# Kmeans in R using multiple tables

Tags: r, data-mining, k-means

I'm new to R. I'm trying to solve a problem -

I have 3 tables-

SubCode - Contains Subject and it's code

```
CompSci C
InfoSci I
Math M
Business B
Journalism J
```

CourseCodeSub - Contains Course code and subject it comes under

```
1 C,I
2 C,I,M
3 B,J,I
4 M,B
5 B,J,M
6 C,M
```

StudentIDCourse - Contains Student ID and Courses taken

```
S1 1,2,6
S2 4,5
S3 5,2,4
S4 1,2,3
S5 3,6
S7 4
```

How do I understand the interest of students in each subject from this data using kmeans?

Comment: As written, your question isn't a good fit for SO. You're asking about how to understand your model rather than asking about programming your model. With revision, your question _might_ be a good fit for Cross Validated.

Comment: k-means is designed for **continuous variables**. It won't yield meaningful results on course data. Wrong tool.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't well posed - so I'll show how to get a kmeans object out, using the number of each "subjects" each student takes. Realistically, you would probably want a PCA of this, then kmeans, but this gives an idea for how to approach it.

You first need to get your data into a sensible format. I'm using dat as CourseCodeSub and dat2 as StudentIDCourse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(subjects = strsplit(as.character(subjects), ",")) %>%
  unnest(subjects)
dat2 <- dat2 %>% 
  mutate(course = strsplit(as.character(course), ",")) %>%
  unnest(course) %>%
  mutate(course = as.numeric(course))
```

Now you data is in long format. Next, let's merge them, and get a data.frame with each student, and the number of each subjects each has taken:

```
totable <- left_join(dat2, dat, by = "course") %>%
  group_by(student, subjects) %>%
  summarise(number = n()) %>%
  spread(subjects, number, fill = 0)

Source: local data frame [6 x 6]

  student     B     C     I     J     M
   (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1      S1     0     3     2     0     2
2      S2     2     0     0     1     2
3      S3     2     1     1     1     3
4      S4     1     2     3     1     1
5      S5     1     1     1     1     1
6      S7     1     0     0     0     1
```

Now we can do a `kmeans`:

```
clustered <- kmeans(totable[,2:6], 3)
plot(totable[,2:6], col = clustered$cluster)
```

[image]

and to see which student is in which cluster:

```
cbind(totable$student, clustered$cluster)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    1
[4,]    4    2
[5,]    5    3
[6,]    6    3
```